# How to implement communication with a Meteor server in flash

Tags: flash, meteor, client-server

I am just starting with Meteor JS.

The idea is to build a client that works on a phone and that can control a game that is created in Flash (as3). (The phone becomes a control pad)

So it would be like :

- client1 : phone
- client2 : phone
- server meteor js
- game developped in flash (a special client ?)

1) Can flash interact with the meteorjs server ?

2) If so, any links or information ?

3) Is this a good idea ? I mean, have people tried MeteorJS in a realtime cient-server game concept ?

Thank-you for any advice or ideas !

Blueweb

Comment: You should try searching for "DDP" and "DDP implementations". As for your questions: Asking for a link is off-topic, asking if it's a good idea is too, asking if people have tried something is slightly so. Please stick to the subject and ask precise questions (here, how to implement communication with a Meteor server in flash, but it may be too broad). Congratulations on your first question, and welcome!

Comment: Should i create a new thread ?

Comment: You can edit your question with the "edit" button.

Comment: Thx, had a hard time finding that btn...

Answer (score 0):

I have no AS3 experience, but you could check the project at https://github.com/acidsound/DDPClientAS3 if you already haven't. Not much activity there though.

A list of DDP Clients is at http://meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients

Comment: Hello. Yes, this list is good, but im not sure that going by DDP is going to be real time. (no observe i suppose). Ill test this and come back here. Thx.

Comment: Hey, DDP is what makes everything real-time.. You could read more about it here https://www.meteor.com/ddp DDP is like "REST for websockets". Like REST, it is a simple, pragmatic approach to providing an API. But it is websocket-based, unlike REST, allowing it to be used to deliver live updates as data changes. Implementation of DDP is simple (it's just a few JSON messages over a websocket) and the spec fits on a couple of pages.